# How To create A Large Size Custom Cursor In Java?

Tags: java, swing, size, custom-cursor

I'm developing a Java Swing app for an award winning password protection system, and I need a large custom cursor [ 80 x 80 ], you might ask why so large, there is an online web demo you may look at to learn why it needs to be so large : http://gatecybertech.net

That large cursor is used on the login page in the above link. Of course you need to create a test password first before you can try the login process.

But anyway, in my Swing app, I hit a limit of 32 x 32 for the largest possible custom cursor, my code looks like the following :

```
Image cursorImage = toolkit.getImage("Cursor_Crosshair.PNG");
Tabular_Panel.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorImage,new Point(0,0),"custom cursor"));
```

The image size of Cursor_Crosshair.PNG is : 80 x 80

But what shows up in the screen is a shrinked version of it at : 32 x 32

So my question is : how can I bypass the size limit on customer cursor image, and make the cursor to show up at the size of 80 x 80 ?

I know the OS might be the reason for the limit, is there a way to overcome it ?

Comment: This may be a limitation implied by the OS

Comment: You could use custom painting, but the cursor would only show inside the bounds of the window.

Comment: @Radiodef : Great idea, I only need it to appear inside a JPanel in my JFrame, any sample code ?

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620188/how-to-set-custom-size-for-cursor-in-swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the glass pane painting approach. This is set up to behave pretty much like setting a custom cursor. The default "arrow" cursor is hidden while the custom cursor is shown, and the custom cursor is hidden when a component has some other cursor set, such as a text box.

Unfortunately, it ended up seeming to require quite a bit of Swing black magic, so I don't like it very much, but it does seem to work correctly. I've done a cursor like this before, but it was for something simpler, so I didn't run in to these issues.

Some of the problems I ran in to are:

- The glass pane intercepts cursor changes (described e.g. on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12347320/2891664)). The only solution I've been able to find is to override [`Component.contains(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#contains-int-int-) to return `false` (described [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/alexfromsun/2006/09/20/well-behaved-glasspane), shown [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090330053106/http://download.java.net/javadesktop/blogs/alexfromsun/2006.09.20/FinalGlassPane.java.html)), but why that works and doesn't seem to break anything else is mysterious.
- Mouse exit events sometimes return a location inside the bounds of the component, so I don't think there's a reliable way to know when the mouse leaves the window except to use a timer.

```
package mcve;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LargeCursor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            JPanel glass = new CustomGlassPane();
            glass.add(new CursorPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setGlassPane(glass);
            // This next call is necessary because JFrame.setGlassPane delegates to the root pane:
            // - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html#setGlassPane-java.awt.Component-
            // - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JFrame.java#l738
            // And JRootPane.setGlassPane may call setVisible(false):
            // - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setGlassPane-java.awt.Component-
            // - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JRootPane.java#l663
            glass.setVisible(true);

            JPanel content = createTestPanel();
            content.setCursor(BlankCursor.INSTANCE);

            frame.setContentPane(content);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static class CustomGlassPane extends JPanel {
        CustomGlassPane() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            super.setOpaque(false);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class CursorPanel extends JPanel {
        final BufferedImage cursorImage;
        Point mouseLocation;

        CursorPanel() {
            try {
                cursorImage = createTransparentImage(
                    ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h2oI.png")));
            } catch (IOException x) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(x);
            }

            setOpaque(false);

            long mask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK;

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener((AWTEvent e) -> {
                switch (e.getID()) {
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED:
                    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED:
                        capturePoint((MouseEvent) e);
                        break;
                }
            }, mask);

            // This turned out to be necessary, because
            // the 'mouse exit' events don't always have
            // a Point location which is outside the pane.
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, (ActionEvent e) -> {
                if (mouseLocation != null) {
                    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, this);
                    if (!contains(p)) {
                        setMouseLocation(null);
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        void capturePoint(MouseEvent e) {
            Component comp = e.getComponent();
            Point onThis = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(comp, e.getPoint(), this);
            boolean drawCursor = contains(onThis);

            if (drawCursor) {
                Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
                if (window instanceof JFrame) {
                    Container content = ((JFrame) window).getContentPane();
                    Point onContent = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(comp, e.getPoint(), content);
                    Component deepest = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(content, onContent.x, onContent.y);
                    if (deepest != null) {
                        if (deepest.getCursor() != BlankCursor.INSTANCE) {
                            drawCursor = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            setMouseLocation(drawCursor ? onThis : null);
        }

        void setMouseLocation(Point mouseLocation) {
            this.mouseLocation = mouseLocation;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (mouseLocation != null) {
                int x = mouseLocation.x - (cursorImage.getWidth() / 2);
                int y = mouseLocation.y - (cursorImage.getHeight() / 2);

                g.drawImage(cursorImage, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }

    static final class BlankCursor {
        static final Cursor INSTANCE =
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB),
                new Point(),
                "BLANK");
    }

    static JPanel createTestPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField("Text Field");
                field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                panel.add(field);
            } else {
                panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
            }
        }

        return panel;
    }

    static BufferedImage createTransparentImage(BufferedImage img) {
        BufferedImage copy =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                               .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                               .getDefaultConfiguration()
                               .createCompatibleImage(img.getWidth(),
                                                      img.getHeight(),
                                                      Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); ++y) {
                int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y) & 0x00FFFFFF;
                int bright = (((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF) + (rgb & 0xFF)) / 3;
                int alpha = 255 - bright;
                copy.setRGB(x, y, (alpha << 24) | rgb);
            }
        }

        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some research and modification, I found the answer :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor
{
  static private MyGlassPane myGlassPane;

  // Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Start creating and adding components.
    JCheckBox changeButton=new JCheckBox("Custom Cursor \"visible\"");
    changeButton.setSelected(false);

    //Set up the content pane, where the "main GUI" lives.
    Container contentPane=frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPane.add(changeButton);

    JButton Button_1=new JButton("<Html><Table Cellpadding=7><Tr><Td>A</Td><Td>B</Td></Tr><Tr><Td>C</Td><Td>D</Td></Tr></Table></Html>");
    Button_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out("Button 1"); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_1);

    JButton Button_2=new JButton("<Html><Table Cellpadding=7><Tr><Td>1</Td><Td>2</Td></Tr><Tr><Td>3</Td><Td>4</Td></Tr></Table></Html>");
    Button_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out("Button 2"); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_2);

    //Set up the menu bar, which appears above the content pane.
    JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu=new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Do nothing"));
    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //Set up the glass pane, which appears over both menu bar
    //and content pane and is an item listener on the change
    //button.
    myGlassPane=new MyGlassPane(changeButton,menuBar,frame.getContentPane());
    changeButton.addItemListener(myGlassPane);
    frame.setGlassPane(myGlassPane);

    //Show the window.
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void out(String message) { System.out.print(message); }

  private static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}

/**
 We have to provide our own glass pane so that it can paint.
 */
class MyGlassPane extends JComponent implements ItemListener
{
  Point point;

  //React to change button clicks.
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
  {
    setVisible(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    try
    {
    if (point!=null)
    {
//      g.setColor(Color.red);
//      g.fillOval(point.x-10,point.y-10,20,20);

      BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Cursor_Crosshair.PNG"));
      g.drawImage(image,point.x-39,point.y-39,null);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }

  public void setPoint(Point p)
  {
    point=p;
  }

  public MyGlassPane(AbstractButton aButton,JMenuBar menuBar,Container contentPane)
  {
    CBListener listener=new CBListener(aButton,menuBar,this,contentPane);
    addMouseListener(listener);
    addMouseMotionListener(listener);
  }
}

/**
 Listen for all events that our check box is likely to be interested in. Redispatch them to the check box.
 */
class CBListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
  Toolkit toolkit;
  Component liveButton;
  JMenuBar menuBar;
  MyGlassPane glassPane;
  Container contentPane;

  public CBListener(Component liveButton,JMenuBar menuBar,MyGlassPane glassPane,Container contentPane)
  {
    toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    this.liveButton=liveButton;
    this.menuBar=menuBar;
    this.glassPane=glassPane;
    this.contentPane=contentPane;
  }

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
  {
//    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,true);
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,true);
  }

  //A basic implementation of redispatching events.
  private void redispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e,boolean repaint)
  {
    Point glassPanePoint=e.getPoint();
    Container container=contentPane;
    Point containerPoint=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane,glassPanePoint,contentPane);
    if (containerPoint.y<0)
    { //we're not in the content pane
      if (containerPoint.y+menuBar.getHeight()>=0)
      {
        //The mouse event is over the menu bar.
        //Could handle specially.
      }
      else
      {
        //The mouse event is over non-system window 
        //decorations, such as the ones provided by
        //the Java look and feel.
        //Could handle specially.
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //The mouse event is probably over the content pane.
      //Find out exactly which component it's over.  
      Component component=SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(container,containerPoint.x,containerPoint.y);

//      if ((component!=null) && (component.equals(liveButton)))
      if ((component!=null))
      {
        //Forward events over the check box.
        Point componentPoint=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane,glassPanePoint,component);
        component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component,e.getID(),e.getWhen(),e.getModifiers(),componentPoint.x,componentPoint.y,e.getClickCount(),e.isPopupTrigger()));
      }
    }

    //Update the glass pane if requested.
    if (repaint)
    {
      glassPane.setPoint(glassPanePoint);
      glassPane.repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

And the Cursor_Crosshair.PNG is like this :
[image]