# How To Implement Large Custom Cursor In Java?

Tags: java, swing, custom-cursor

This question is related to my previous question : [How To create A Large Size Custom Cursor In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333423/how-to-create-a-large-size-custom-cursor-in-java)

If you are curious about what is it used for, you can find a practical use case for an award winning password protection system called GATE [ Graphic Access Tabular Entry ] at : http://gatecybertech.net/

After the previous question I found a way to create a large custom cursor, and the working answer is posted in my previous post. But in order to achieve it, I have to click a checkbox first, now I want to be able to create a large custom cursor without first need to click a checkbox, so I modified my code to look like the following without a checkbox :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor_Simple
{
  static private MyGlassPane_Simple myGlassPane;

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor_Simple");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//    JCheckBox changeButton=new JCheckBox("Custom Cursor \"visible\"");
//    changeButton.setSelected(false);

    Container contentPane=frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//    contentPane.add(changeButton);

    JButton Button_1=new JButton("<Html><Table Cellpadding=7><Tr><Td>A</Td><Td>B</Td></Tr><Tr><Td>C</Td><Td>D</Td></Tr></Table></Html>");
    Button_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out("Button 1"); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_1);

    JButton Button_2=new JButton("<Html><Table Cellpadding=7><Tr><Td>1</Td><Td>2</Td></Tr><Tr><Td>3</Td><Td>4</Td></Tr></Table></Html>");
    Button_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out("Button 2"); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_2);

    JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu=new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Do nothing"));
    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    // Set up the glass pane, which appears over both menu bar and content pane and is an item listener on the change button.
//    myGlassPane=new MyGlassPane_Simple(changeButton,menuBar,frame.getContentPane());
    myGlassPane=new MyGlassPane_Simple(menuBar,frame.getContentPane());
//    changeButton.addItemListener(myGlassPane);
    frame.setGlassPane(myGlassPane);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void out(String message) { System.out.print(message); }

  private static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args) { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); } }); }
}

// We have to provide our own glass pane so that it can paint.
class MyGlassPane_Simple extends JComponent implements ItemListener
{
  Point point;

//  public MyGlassPane_Simple(AbstractButton aButton,JMenuBar menuBar,Container contentPane)
  public MyGlassPane_Simple(JMenuBar menuBar,Container contentPane)
  {
//    CBListener_Simple listener=new CBListener_Simple(aButton,menuBar,this,contentPane);
    CBListener_Simple listener=new CBListener_Simple(menuBar,this,contentPane);
    addMouseListener(listener);
    addMouseMotionListener(listener);
  }

  // React to change button clicks.
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) { setVisible(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED); }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    try
    {
      if (point!=null)
      {
//      g.setColor(Color.red);
//      g.fillOval(point.x-10,point.y-10,20,20);

        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Cursor_Crosshair.PNG"));
        g.drawImage(image,point.x-39,point.y-39,null);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }

  public void setPoint(Point p) { point=p; }
}

// Listen for all events that our check box is likely to be interested in. Redispatch them to the check box.
class CBListener_Simple extends MouseInputAdapter
{
  Toolkit toolkit;
  Component liveButton;
  JMenuBar menuBar;
  MyGlassPane_Simple glassPane;
  Container contentPane;

//  public CBListener_Simple(Component liveButton,JMenuBar menuBar,MyGlassPane_Simple glassPane,Container contentPane)
  public CBListener_Simple(JMenuBar menuBar,MyGlassPane_Simple glassPane,Container contentPane)
  {
    toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    this.liveButton=liveButton;
    this.menuBar=menuBar;
    this.glassPane=glassPane;
    this.contentPane=contentPane;
  }

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
  {
//    redispatchMouseEvent(e,false);
    redispatchMouseEvent(e,true);
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,false); }
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,false); }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,false); }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,false); }
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,false); }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { redispatchMouseEvent(e,true); }

  // A basic implementation of redispatching events.
  private void redispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e,boolean repaint)
  {
    Point glassPanePoint=e.getPoint();
    Container container=contentPane;
    Point containerPoint=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane,glassPanePoint,contentPane);

    if (containerPoint.y<0)
    { // We're not in the content pane
      if (containerPoint.y+menuBar.getHeight()>=0)
      {
        // The mouse event is over the menu bar. Could handle specially.
      }
      else
      {
        // The mouse event is over non-system window decorations, such as the ones provided by the Java look and feel. Could handle specially.
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // The mouse event is probably over the content pane. Find out exactly which component it's over.  
      Component component=SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(container,containerPoint.x,containerPoint.y);

//      if ((component!=null) && (component.equals(liveButton)))
      if ((component!=null))
      {
        // Forward events over the check box.
        Point componentPoint=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane,glassPanePoint,component);
        component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component,e.getID(),e.getWhen(),e.getModifiers(),componentPoint.x,componentPoint.y,e.getClickCount(),e.isPopupTrigger()));
      }
    }

    // Update the glass pane if requested.
    if (repaint)
    {
      glassPane.setPoint(glassPanePoint);
      glassPane.repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

The 3 classes in this app are :

```
Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor_Simple.java
MyGlassPane_Simple.java
CBListener_Simple.java
```

They are all the classes needed to run this demo app.

The Cursor_Crosshair.PNG image looks like this : [image]

But, it's not showing large custom cursor any more, I wonder what I did wrong, what should I do based on this existing code to show large custom cursor when mouse enters the app window ?

Comment: It is not possible to run this code without `CBListener_Simple` and the png file. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Just added more details, now it's a MCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Radiodef for the inspirational answer to my previous question at : [How To create A Large Size Custom Cursor In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333423/how-to-create-a-large-size-custom-cursor-in-java)

Here is a modified version of the answer that fits my requirements :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor_Simple
{
  static Insets An_Inset=new Insets(0,0,0,0);

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Demo_Large_Custom_Cursor_Simple");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container contentPane=frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2*80+15,2*80+15));

    int Font_Size=6;
    String Color="blue",Font_Face="Monospaced",
           Token_1="<Html>"+
                   "  <Table Border=0 Cellspacing=3 Cellpadding=3>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">1</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">A</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2664</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u203b</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "  </Table>"+
                   "</Html>",
           Token_2="<Html>"+
                   "  <Table Border=0 Cellspacing=3 Cellpadding=3>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">2</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">B</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2660</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2638</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "  </Table>"+
                   "</Html>",
           Token_3="<Html>"+
                   "  <Table Border=0 Cellspacing=3 Cellpadding=3>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">3</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">C</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2667</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2668</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "  </Table>"+
                   "</Html>",
           Token_4="<Html>"+
                   "  <Table Border=0 Cellspacing=3 Cellpadding=3>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">4</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">D</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "    <Tr><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u2663</Font></Td><Td Align=Center><Font Size="+Font_Size+" Color="+Color+">\u262f</Font></Td></Tr>"+
                   "  </Table>"+
                   "</Html>";
    JButton Button_1=new JButton(Token_1);
    Button_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_1.setFont(new Font(Font_Face,0,16));
    Button_1.setMargin(An_Inset);
    Button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out(Button_1.getText().replaceAll("<[^>]*>"," ").replaceAll("( )+"," ")); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_1);

    JButton Button_2=new JButton(Token_2);
    Button_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_2.setFont(new Font(Font_Face,0,16));
    Button_2.setMargin(An_Inset);
    Button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out(Button_2.getText().replaceAll("<[^>]*>"," ").replaceAll("( )+"," ")); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_2);

    JButton Button_3=new JButton(Token_3);
    Button_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_3.setFont(new Font(Font_Face,0,16));
    Button_3.setMargin(An_Inset);
    Button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out(Button_3.getText().replaceAll("<[^>]*>"," ").replaceAll("( )+"," ")); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_3);

    JButton Button_4=new JButton(Token_4);
    Button_4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
    Button_4.setFont(new Font(Font_Face,0,16));
    Button_4.setMargin(An_Inset);
    Button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { Out(Button_4.getText().replaceAll("<[^>]*>"," ").replaceAll("( )+"," ")); } });
    contentPane.add(Button_4);

    JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu=new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Do nothing"));
    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JPanel glass=new CustomGlassPane();
    glass.add(new CursorPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setGlassPane(glass);
    // This next call is necessary because JFrame.setGlassPane delegates to the root pane:
    // - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html#setGlassPane-java.awt.Component-
    // - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JFrame.java#l738
    // And JRootPane.setGlassPane may call setVisible(false):
    // - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setGlassPane-java.awt.Component-
    // - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JRootPane.java#l663
    glass.setVisible(true);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  static class CustomGlassPane extends JPanel
  {
    CustomGlassPane()
    {
      super(new BorderLayout());
      super.setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int x,int y) { return false; }
  }

  static class CursorPanel extends JPanel
  {
    final BufferedImage cursorImage;
    Point mouseLocation;

    CursorPanel()
    {
      try { cursorImage=ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Cursor_Crosshair.PNG")); }
      catch (IOException x) { throw new UncheckedIOException(x); }

      setOpaque(false);
      long mask=AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK|AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK;
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener((AWTEvent e)->
      {
        switch (e.getID())
        {
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED :
          case  MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED :
          case   MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED :
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED : capturePoint((MouseEvent)e);
            break;
        }
      },mask);

      // This turned out to be necessary, because the 'mouse exit' events don't always have a Point location which is outside the pane.
      Timer timer=new Timer(100,(ActionEvent e)->
      {
        if (mouseLocation!=null)
        {
          Point p=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
          SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p,this);
          if (!contains(p)) setMouseLocation(null);
        }
      });
      timer.setRepeats(true);
      timer.start();
    }

    void capturePoint(MouseEvent e)
    {
      Component comp=e.getComponent();
      Point onThis=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(comp,e.getPoint(),this);
      boolean drawCursor=contains(onThis);

      if (drawCursor)
      {
        Window window=SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
        if (window instanceof JFrame)
        {
          Container content=((JFrame)window).getContentPane();
          Point onContent=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(comp,e.getPoint(),content);
          Component deepest=SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(content,onContent.x,onContent.y);
          if (deepest==null) drawCursor=false;
        }
      }

      setMouseLocation(drawCursor?onThis:null);
    }

    void setMouseLocation(Point mouseLocation)
    {
      this.mouseLocation=mouseLocation;
      repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      if (mouseLocation!=null)
      {
        int x=mouseLocation.x-(cursorImage.getWidth()/2)+1;
        int y=mouseLocation.y-(cursorImage.getHeight()/2)+1;

        g.drawImage(cursorImage,x,y,this);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void out(String message) { System.out.print(message); }
  private static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args) { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); } }); }
}
```

Cursor_Crosshair.PNG looks like this : [image]